# Getting authorization error while accessing google merchant product list

Tags: php, google-apis-explorer

I was trying to access Google Merchant Products which was added by Feed and followed the API reference https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/products/list#try-it. When I use Google OAuth 2.0 It asks login to google account and get response of all products and when I use API key "https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/[MERCHANT_ID]/products?key=[KEY]" I get following response
`

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "Login Required",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Login Required"
    }
}
```

`

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC Can you help me with this?

Comment: I have no idea how you come up with this `key` parameter, did you just make it up or think it will work like magic? The documentation specifically say that it [require authorization](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/how-tos/authorizing) so follow the documentation before asking why it's not working

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for your comment. I've authorized the request using OAuth and now can access 

`require_once 'Google/Service/ShoppingContent.php';

$service = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent($client);`

I'm following https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/products#productslist

My question is how can I call all product list using generated API Key

Answer (score 0):

API keys can't be used for authentication (it wouldn't be secure), they're only for authorization. In other words, API keys can allow you to call the API, but they can't be used to validate who you are (and thus what data you have permission to access).

As such, it looks like you'll want to use OAuth 2.0 in this case, instead of (or in addition to) an API key.

Or alternately, if you're not looking to authenticate as a machine (a Cloud project) instead of an actual user, you may be able to grant a Service Account access and use that type of authentication instead.

Comment: I need to fetch all products and show in a page when any user opens my website. In this case how can I implement OAuth 2.0 ? Any random user doesn't need to sign in to view the products.

Comment: Looks like this may be what you want: https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/quickstart#retrieve_a_service_account_key_for_authentication